# How to handle C command line argument flags in a neater way?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, command-line-arguments

I have this little piece of C code, which takes a set of command-line arguments `--help`, `-h`, `-d` and `-o` (each correspondingly representing "Help", "Hexadecimal", "Decimal", "Octal"), and I am calling certain functions depending in which argument is passed, `-h` will call `hexaFlag()`, `-dh` will call `hexaFlag()` and `decFlag()`. However, in order to do this, I am employing a block of `if else` that is messy. Is there any less convoluted way to achieve this? I was told to use a `switch` statement, but I do not know how I could use it here considering I am checking for different conditions each time.

`main()` function of the code I am referring to:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        if(argc == 1){
                printf("%s",usage());
                printf("Use --help for more options.\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0){
                printf("%s", usage());
                printf("Options are:\n  -h = Hexadecimal values\n  -d = Decimal values\n  -o = Octal values\n  --help = Shows this message\n");
        }
        else if(strchr(argv[1], '-') != NULL){
                if(strchr(argv[1], 'h') != NULL){
                        hexaFlag(argc, argv);
                }
                if(strchr(argv[1], 'd') != NULL){
                        decFlag(2, argc, argv);
                }
                if(strchr(argv[1], 'o') != NULL){
                        octaFlag(argc, argv);
                }
        }
        else {
                decFlag(1, argc, argv);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at [`getopt()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) and [example of `getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html).

Comment: Regarding `getopt` (and `getopt_long`, which you want), there are portable open-source implementations that can be used in your own code. There are also *plenty* of other libraries available that help with parsing command-line options and arguments, if you just search a little.

Comment: First, take the option parsing out of `main`.  Do all the parsing in a function which takes a `struct args *` and sets its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify the function signature a bit to make them consistent.  That would allow you to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>

void hexaFlag(int x, int argc, char **argv) { printf("%d:%s\n", x, __func__); }
void decFlag(int x, int argc, char **argv)  { printf("%d:%s\n", x, __func__); }
void octaFlag(int x, int argc, char **argv) { printf("%d:%s\n", x, __func__); }

struct args {
        void (*f)(int, int, char **);
        int x;
};

void
parse_args(int argc, char *argv[], struct args *A) 
{
        int c;
        if( argc == 1 || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help") ){
                printf("usage: %s [-hdo] [--help] arg [arg...]\n",
                        basename(argv[0]));
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        A->f = decFlag;
        A->x = 1;

        while( (c = getopt(argc, argv, "hdo")) != -1 ) {
                switch( c ){
                case 'h': A->f = hexaFlag; break;
                case 'd': A->f = decFlag; A->x = 2; break;
                case 'o': A->f = octaFlag; break;
                default:  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        struct args A;
        parse_args(argc, argv, &A);
        A.f(A.x, argc, argv);
        return 0;
}
```

You should probably not pass argc/argv directly to the worker functions, but should extract what you need from them into the struct args in parse_args().

Answer (score 0):

My basic switch processing (example), very functional but maybe not beautiful, is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=0, number, files=0;

  /* process switches;  other prms are considered files  (2)
     that are opened for input/output.  Files not  specified
     are taken as stdin and stdout. Prms can be in any order.
  */

  while (++i < argc)
    switch (argv[i][0]) {
      case '-': while (*++argv[i])
                  switch (*argv[i]) {
                  case 'N':
                        ++argv[i]; number= 0;
                        while (isdigit(*argv[i]))
                            number = number *10 + *argv[i]++ - '0';
                        argv[i]--;
                        break;

                    case 'P' : printf ("Prm: P\n"); break;
                    case 'O' : printf ("Prm: O\n"); break;
                    case 'o' : printf ("Prm: o\n"); break;
                  default :
                    printf ("Bad switch %c, ignored.\n",*argv[i]);
                  }
                break;

      default :
        switch (files) {
        case 0: if ((inf=fopen(argv[i],"r")) == 0)
                    pexit("Error opening input file %s.", argv[i]);
                files++; break;
        case 1: if ((outf=fopen(argv[i],"w")) == 0)
                    pexit ("Error creating output file %s.", argv[i]);
                files++; break;
        case 2: fprintf (stderr,"Too many file arguments: %s ignored.\n",argv[i]);
                break;
        } /* end switch files */
      } /* end switch argc */

    if (files <1) inf = stdin;
    if (files <2) outf = stdout;
```

Comment: `Input file %s not found` is a misleading error message if `fopen` fails because of a permissions problem.  Don't guess at the reason for the error.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - message fixed. You like the rest?

Comment: As long as `pexit` adds the system error, that seems okay, but you're going to get a newline between your message and the system error that seems odd. IMO it is better to have the system error on the same line as the rest of the message.  (eg, the behavior of `perror`  But it seems that "Too many file arguments" ought to be written to stderr.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, fixed that too. However the beauty (or disapproval) is of course in the processing.